# Update 2 fields - push last digit from 1 field to the beginning of another field

Tags: sql

I have 2 fields in my SQL table. One has 5 digits (ex: 12345) and the 2nd field has 2 digits (ex: 99) and I need to know if there is a way to take the LAST digit from the first field and push it to the beginning of the 2nd field. So the first field would be 1234 and the 2nd field would be 599 ???

Comment: Column data types? Dbms?

Comment: Perhaps, if you explain what you're trying to accomplish, we can help you more.

Comment: Sorry about that --  

Here are more details

First column is a CountyCode column and has 5 digits, it should only have FOUR digits and the last digit needs to be pushed to the 2nd column (which is the CityCode column)

So if the CountyCode column has like 38799 and the CityCode shows 00, I need to update it so the CountyCode says 3879 and CityCode now says 900

Does that make more sense? sorry if it's a bad explanation :(

Comment: So I need to update ALL rows for both columns

Comment: Still no answer on datatypes and dbms...

Comment: Sorry.... CountyZip datatype is char(5) and City datatype is char(3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET Column2 = RIGHT(Column1, 1) + COALESCE(Column2, ''),
        Column1 = LEFT(Column1, LEN(Column1)-1)
    WHERE COALESCE(LEN(Column1), 0) > 1;
```

Comment: So this will take the 5th character from one field and append it to the beginning of the next field?

Comment: @Ninja-Mary This will take the *last* character of `Column1` and make it the first character of `Column2`.

Comment: Another question. For "Column2" and "Column1" - do I just put the name of the column?

Ex: One column title (field name) is CountyZip and the other is City

Comment: CountyZip datatype is char(5) and City datatype is char(3)

Comment: @Ninja-Mary Yes, you need to replace my made up names with the real table and column names.

Comment: So like this?  

IF the Column I am TAKING the last character for is "Column 1" and the Column I am ADDING It to the front of is "Column 2" ?

Comment: UPDATE dbo.AdmUsaTax
    SET City = RIGHT(CountyZip, 1) + COALESCE(City, ''),
        CountyZip = LEFT(CountyZip, LEN(CountyZip)-1)
    WHERE COALESCE(LEN(CountyZip), 0) > 1;

Comment: and then what would I add to basically say "Unless the City field has 3 characters"  (then don't do anything)  ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "typical" way to do this.

```
update t
    set col1 = left(col1, length(col1) - 1),
        col2 = concat(right(col1, 1), col2);
```

The exact details depend on the database.

Notes:

- This sort of assumes the values are stored as strings, although the logic will convert back and forth from numbers.
- The `left()` and `right()` functions may differ by database, although most databases do support them.
- `concat()` may be replaced by an appropriate operator, depending on the database ('||', '+', '&', come to mind).
- `length()` is sometimes called `len()`.

Comment: Here are more details

First column is a CountyCode column and has 5 digits, it should only have FOUR digits and the last digit needs to be pushed to the 2nd column (which is the CityCode column)

So if the CountyCode column has like 38799 and the CityCode shows 00, I need to update it so the CountyCode says 3879 and CityCode now says 900

Does that make more sense? sorry if it's a bad explanation

Answer (score 0):

And if it's integer columns:

```
update tablename set
   c1 = c1/10,
   c2 = mod(c1,10)*dpower(10,ceiling(dlog10(c2)))+c2
```